# ng-repeat vs reading specific results from LocalStorage in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an **app intended to work 100% offline** that displays 100 objects from an array using ng-repeat on the first page.

All results are recorded to and read from **LocalStorage**.

The ng-repeat works fantastic, but I'm currently building a filter and wonder **how can I manage to display results not included in the first 100 item list**.

For instance, I want to be able to display results upon date range. All objects have a date property, and the DateRangePicker works OK binding with the model of the input once a date range is selected, but in order to display all results matching this range, I assume ng-repeat is no longer useful, as have to be able to make a call into LocalStorage and retrieve data from there.

I'm a bit lost conceptually on which would be the next step, as my Angular skills are not brilliant.

Any pointers on how to procede?

Here's how my current ng-repeat list looks like:

```
<div class="row wop-row" 
     ng-repeat="record in recordlist | filter: search | limitTo : -100" 
     ng-class="{ 'wop-cancelled': record.cancelled, 'wop-commented' : record.comment}">
      <div class="col-md-1">{{record.date}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">{{record.time}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1"><strong>{{record.car}}</strong></div>
      <div class="col-md-2">{{record.driver}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-2">{{record.from}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1" ng-show="editItem == false" ng-hide="editItem">{{record.pax}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-1" ng-show="editItem == true && !record.arrival" ng-hide="!editItem">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="record.pax">
            <option>Driver</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
          </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

And my filter:

```
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <input type='text' 
           date-range-picker 
           placeholder="Date range" 
           class="form-control" 
           id="datetimepicker1" 
           data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" 
           ng-model="search.date"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Time" ng-model="search.time">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Car" ng-model="search.car">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Driver" ng-model="search.driver">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="From" ng-model="search.from">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Pax" ng-model="search.pax">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question it appears you are basically doing the right thing. You just need to make your filter call a function that does the appropriate filtering of the objects.

```
<div class="row wop-row" 
 ng-repeat="record in recordlist | filter: mysearch(record) | limitTo : -100" 
 ng-class="{ 'wop-cancelled': record.cancelled, 'wop-commented' : record.comment}">
```

and then

```
 $scope.mysearch = function(value) {

       return function(value) {
          // Do whatever the current filter is here. Like checking each 'value' to be
          // in a date range if the user has chosen a date. 
       }
 };
```

Comment: So I can make a custom filter that will loop through all the objects of the array and display the results?

Comment: Essentially when recordlist changes your list of items in the ng-repeat will update. I usually keep the entire list is one variable, like 'completeList' and then the list to display in another like 'filteredList'. Use the 'filteredList' in your ng-repeat.  When the user clicks on a Date you can go through the completeList and populate filteredList with only the appropriate items. That will cause your list on the screen to show only those items.  There are many ways you can do it, that is just one.

Comment: I found this sentence that says that well:  ngRepeat automatically updates the view in response to the changing number of items returned by the filter. The process is completely transparent to the developer

Comment: I've never seen it done like this, populating a second list with the filtered results from the entire array. Normally I've only seen it filtering all the results at once, from the completeList. Do you have some example somewhere?